# Pulumi failing to create alloydb instance on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pulumi, pulumi-python, google-alloydb

I am encountering an issue while trying to create a GCP instance for alloydb using pulumi. Although I was able to create the alloydb cluster successfully, the instance creation is not working. Additionally, the error message provided is hard to trace back. Here is the pulumi code:

```
default_instance = gcp.alloydb.Instance(prefix,
    cluster=default_cluster.name,
    instance_id="primary-instance",
    instance_type="PRIMARY",
    machine_config=gcp.alloydb.InstanceMachineConfigArgs(
        cpu_count=2,
    ))
```

Output:

```
Diagnostics:
  gcp:alloydb:Instance (development):
    error: 1 error occurred:
        * Error waiting to create Instance: Error waiting for Creating Instance: Error code 13, message: an internal error has occurred
```